# fitting a GUID field into a smaller field without losing uniqueness

Tags: guid

I need to send a GUID PK field (length = 36) to a downstream system that will only accept 20-char long.  It is cost-prohibitive to increase the length of the field in the downstream system.
If I truncate the field then I lose its uniqueness.

Any way to stuff a 36 characters long GUID into a varchar(20) field without losing uniqueness?

thank you
Kathy

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Is the downstream system receiving GUIDs from multiple sources, or just you?

Answer (score 2):

Since a Varchar(20) is 20 bytes and a GUID is 16, you should just be able to fit it in by [ASCII85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)-encoding the binary GUID.

Comment: Do 36 character long GUIDs really only occupy 16 bytes?

Comment: A binary GUID is indeed 16 bytes, it is only the hexadecimal representation that is 36 characters.